# Example on Jordan basis and Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the canonical Jordan form and Jordan basis of the operator $f$ given by matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Remark:** I know that this is a standard example on linear algebra but I have learnt this couple days and I would like to check is my solution is correct?

**Solution:** It is easy to check that characteristic polynomial is equal to $-(\lambda+1)^3$. Hence the operator $(f+\text{id})$ is nilpotent. The matrix of this operator is $$A+E=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ and the rank of this matrix is one. Easy to check that $(A+E)^2=0$ and the rank is zero. So it means that Jordan canonical form of $f+\text{id}$ has two cells $J_2(0)$ and $J_1(0)$, where $J_d(\lambda)$ is square $d\times d$ matrix with 1's on superdiagonal, $\lambda$'s on diagonal and other elements are zero. So the Jordan canonical form of $f$ is $$J=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Let's construct the Jordan basis. Since $(f+\text{id})^2=0$ then $\ker (f+\text{id})^2=\mathbb{R^3}$ and easy to check that $\ker(f+\text{id})=\langle (0,1,0),(-1,0,1)\rangle$. Take a vector in $\ker (f+\text{id})^2$ which is not in $\ker (f+\text{id})$ for example, $(0,0,-1)$. Then applying $f+\text{id}$ to it we'll get $(1,1,-1)$.

The last step is to take vector from $\ker(f+\text{id})$ which is linearly independent with $(1,1,-1)$. And $(-1,1,1)$ is such a vector.

Let's label them: $e_1=(1,1,-1), e_2=(0,0,-1), e_3=(-1,1,1)$. So $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is Jordan basis such that the matrix of operator $f$ in this basis is $J$.

I have missed some calculations and clarifications. Can anyone check is everything ok here, please?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. The only thing to keep in mind is when we are selecting the basis for the eigenvalue with multiplicity, sometimes it's good (though not required) to keep the basis orthogonal. So for $e_3$ I would select $e_3=(-1,2,1)$. For this problem alone, it's a matter of preference. (If you need to work further with those vectors, orthogonality can save some work).

In addition, your way of finding the cells of the Jordan matrix works fine in 3d, but won't necessarily work in higher dimensions. For example, for polynomial $(\lambda+1)^4=0$ and $(f+id)^2=0$, there are two possibilities: $(J_2,J_2)$ and $(J_2,J_1,J_1)$. But probably you know that.

Comment: To be honest i did not get your addition. Could you give some concrete example?